# List all the customers who are not active, with MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, join, inner-join, where-clause

I have complicated questions that need your help:

Q: List all the customers who are not active.

- Customer table: customerid, name, address....
- Mobile table: customer id, mobileid, status (Null and Cancelled date)

How to write the SQL query to check who is the customers not active based on status?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM customerDB 
JOIN mobileDB ON customerDB.customerID = mobileDB.customerID
WHERE status IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer as c
JOIN Mobile as m on m.customer_id = c.customer_id
WHERE m.status is not Null
```

You can further expand this query to include other values:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customer as c
JOIN Mobile as m on m.customer_id = c.customer_id
WHERE 1=1
and m.status is not Null
and c.name = 'john'
and c.mobileid in (293478, 2834783, 282383, 672723)
```